# Clicking Radio type buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

Well this java script should click the buttons (making an animation slideshow) the thing is i cant manage the code to click the button, and i cant find the error, seems to be running

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var seconds = 0;
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);

    function setTime() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds == 5) {
            document.getElementById('i2').value = true;
        } else if (seconds == 10) {
            document.getElementById('i3').value = true;
        } else if (seconds == 15) {
            document.getElementById('i4').value = true;
        } else if(seconds == 20) {
            document.getElementById('i1').value = true;
            seconds == 0;
        }
    }

</script>
<div class="slideshow" onload="setTime()">
  <input type="radio" id="i1" name="images" checked/>
  <input type="radio" id="i2" name="images" />
  <input type="radio" id="i3" name="images" />
  <input type="radio" id="i4" name="images" />
</div>
</html>
```

I tried `.checked` `.click()` `.value`, its not working, something is messing up the action but again I cant figure out what it is.

Comment: As an aside: `cheked` should be `checked`

Comment: i may be wrong but if you check the value of seconds you will see it resets every time you run the function

Comment: thanks to both of you, i read the reset after i solved it, but both of your comments are right, and i spend way to much time on it, so thanks both of you.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` is the value that will be submitted with the form data **if** the radio button is checked.

You need to modify the `checked` property if you want to change its state from unchecked to checked.

```js
var seconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  seconds++;
  if (seconds == 5) {
    document.getElementById('i2').checked = true;
  } else if (seconds == 10) {
    document.getElementById('i3').checked = true;
  } else if (seconds == 15) {
    document.getElementById('i4').checked = true;
  } else if (seconds == 20) {
    document.getElementById('i1').checked = true;
    seconds == 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="i1" name="images" checked/>
<input type="radio" id="i2" name="images" />
<input type="radio" id="i3" name="images" />
<input type="radio" id="i4" name="images" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the *checked* property you have to set not the *value*.

**Please Note:** Your script is executing before the DOM is fully loaded. Either you have to place the script at the end of the page or wrap the code with

[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event load should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is an incredibly common mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be much more appropriate, so be cautious.

You also have typo in `seconds == 0;`, should be the assignment operator (`=`) instead of comparison.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var seconds = 0;
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);

    function setTime() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds == 5) {
            document.getElementById('i2').checked = true;
        } else if (seconds == 10) {
            document.getElementById('i3').checked = true;
        } else if (seconds == 15) {
            document.getElementById('i4').checked = true;
        } else if(seconds == 20) {
            document.getElementById('i1').checked = true;
            seconds = 0;
        }
    }
  });
    

</script>
<div class="slideshow" onload='setTime()'>
  <input type="radio" id="i1" name="images" checked/>
  <input type="radio" id="i2" name="images" />
  <input type="radio" id="i3" name="images" />
  <input type="radio" id="i4" name="images" />
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer.

Comment: "Your script is executing before the DOM is fully loaded. " — That doesn't actually matter given the shortness of the document combined with the five-second delay before the script attempts to update the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

it had 2 typos cheked and == its working now

```js
var seconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds == 5) {
        document.getElementById('i2').checked = true;
    } else if (seconds == 10) {
        document.getElementById('i3').checked = true;
    } else if (seconds == 15) {
        document.getElementById('i4').checked = true;
    } else if (seconds == 20) {
        document.getElementById('i1').checked = true;
        seconds = 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow" onload="setTime()">
  <input type="radio" id="i1" name="images" checked/>
  <input type="radio" id="i2" name="images" />
  <input type="radio" id="i3" name="images" />
  <input type="radio" id="i4" name="images" />
<div>
```

I had == 0; and cheked as an input. Thanks for your suggestions